With docker deployment of jenkins 2.2, how do I upgrade to jenkin 2.4 version and what are the steps required?
I used docker to deploy jenkins 2.2, 1 master, 9 slave, slave machine is mainly for build. I want to upgrade jenkins 2.2 to jenkins 2.4, from the official website to download the jenkins 2.4 war package, in the container to replace the previous 2.2 war package, then After restarting the container, the container can't start, the log shows that it needs to use JDK 11 version, while the 2.2 jenkins uses JDK 8 version.
My question is for the version of jenkins 2.2 deployed using docker, if I want to upgrade to jenkins 2.4, can I do it in one step? Or do I need to do a multi-step upgrade before I can upgrade from jenkins 2.2 to 2.4?  What are the upgrade methods and steps?
